# What exactly is a product measure?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

If we have $(X \times Y, \overline{\Sigma \times \tau}, \lambda)$ a complete measure space with underlying complete spaces $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ and $(Y, \tau, \nu)$, and $\lambda = \mu \times \nu$, what exactly is a product measure?

The reason I am asking this is that if we have a function $f \in L^{1}(d\lambda)$, then clearly $\int \limits_{X \times Y} |f| \,d\lambda < \infty$.  But we can say $f = f\chi_{ \{ (x,y) \mid f(x,y) \neq 0 \} }$, where $\chi_{ \{ (x,y) \mid f(x,y) \neq 0 \} }$ is the characteristic function of $ \{ (x,y) \mid f(x,y) \neq 0 \}$.

Since the two functions are equal, we get that $\int \limits_{X \times Y} |f| \,d\lambda = \int \limits_{X \times Y} |f\chi_{ \{ (x,y) \mid f(x,y) \neq 0 \} }| \,d\lambda = \int \limits_{X \times Y} |f| \,d( \chi_{ \{ (x,y) \mid f(x,y) \neq 0 \} } \,d\lambda)$.

This means that $f \in L^{1}(d( \chi_{ \{ (x,y) \mid f(x,y) \neq 0 \} } \,d\lambda))$.

**But my professor said that the measure $\chi_{ \{ (x,y) \mid f(x,y) \neq 0 \} } \,d\lambda$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure, but not necessarily a *product measure*.  What does that mean?  Why can we integrate with it over $X \times Y$ if it is not a product measure?**  Does it possibly mean that the measure is not necessarily defined on the product $\sigma$-algebra?  This measure is defined on the product $\sigma$-algebra, so that can't be it...

Note that if $E \in \overline{\Sigma \times \tau}$, then the measure of $E$ with respect to $\chi_{ \{ (x,y) \mid f(x,y) \neq 0 \} } \,d\lambda$ is defined to be $\int \limits_{E} \chi_{ \{ (x,y) \mid f(x,y) \neq 0 \} } \,d\lambda$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure

Comment: @Timkinsella I checked the wikipedia site out already, but it didn't help me answer my question. :(

Comment: Are you looking for the definition of a product measure?  If so, what's unclear about the definition in the article?  Maybe you're instead looking for criteria that tell you when a measure is "factorable"?

Comment: @Timkinsella I'm wondering why the measure I described in my question details is "not necessarily" a product measure.

Comment: Why would you think it would be?

Comment: @Timkinsella Because it is a measure and (I think) it is defined on the product $\sigma$-algebra.  What is to stop it from being a product measure?

Comment: Read the third paragraph in the wiki article. Being defined on the product sigma algebra isn't the only requirement.

Comment: @Timkinsella Thanks, Nate Eldredge's answer is exactly what you were trying to say.

Comment: You're welcome.  I should have realized you were asking for a counterexample :)

Comment: @Timkinsella Actually, your reference to the third paragraph of the wiki article that said the product measure must satisfy $\lambda(A \times B) = \mu(A)\nu(B)$ is what helped me to understand Nate's answer.  I didn't realize that was an additional property of a product measure.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $(X, \Sigma)$ and $(Y, \tau)$ are measurable spaces, then a measure $\lambda$ on $(X \times Y, \Sigma \times \tau)$ is said to be a product measure if there exist measures $\mu, \nu$ on $(X, \Sigma)$, $(Y, \tau)$ respectively, such that $\lambda = \mu \times \nu$.  That is, for each $A \in \Sigma$, $B \in \tau$, we have $\lambda(A \times B) = \mu(A) \nu(B)$.

Not every measure on $(X \times Y, \Sigma \times \tau)$ is a product measure.  For a simple example, take $(X, \Sigma) = (Y, \tau) = (\{a,b\}, \mathcal{P}(\{a,b\}))$ to be sets with two points, and define, for instance, $\lambda(\{(a,a)\}) = \lambda(\{(b,b)\}) = 1$ and  $\lambda(\{(a,b)\}) = \lambda(\{(b,a)\}) = 0$, defined for other sets by additivity.  Suppose $\lambda = \mu \times \nu$. Since $\{(a,b)\} = \{a\} \times \{b\}$, we must have either $\mu(\{a\})=0$, contradicting $\lambda(\{(a,a)\}) = \mu(\{a\}) \nu(\{a\}) = 1$, or $\nu(\{b\})=0$, contradicting $\lambda(\{(b,b)\}) = \mu(\{b\}) \nu(\{b\}) = 1$.  Either way we reach a contradiction, so $\lambda$ is not a product measure.

Comment: but isn't is true that the product measure can be extended in an unique way on $\Sigma \times \tau$? So only one product measure exists, doesn't it?

Comment: I understand what you mean now.  Thank you very much.  Also, I would be interested to know the answer to the question asked by @Ant if you have time.